# Need to sync two tables from different databases in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, synchronization

Usually to sync a table with in the network I can write a simple sql query and run it to sync the tables, but what if the source database is different(could be db2, mssql, mysql, oracle - from where I can get the data in to destination table).

How should I go about writing the code in java to achieve this?. I know I can create dblinks in java to fetch data from external network database but dblinks works only with database of same type. I am not able to figure out the implementation in my head. Please point me in the right direction so I can take baby steps and learn the same as I am new to java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with plain JDBC. Code example, not tested:

```
void migrate() throws SQLException {
        Connection connA = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl");
        Connection connB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.33/test");

        PreparedStatement stmA = connA.prepareStatement("select * from product where 1=1");
        PreparedStatement stmB = connB.prepareStatement("insert into prod values(?,?,?,?)");

        ResultSet rs = stmA.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                stmB.setObject(i + 1, rs.getObject(i + 1));
            }
            stmB.executeUpdate();
        }

        connA.close();
        connB.close();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Peter I have already tried something similar to what you have answered. Is there any optimized way to do it ? like using API's(example: oracle api) for implementing the same ? Please help!!

Comment: You are `new to Java` and asks for optimization. What issues do you have, memory, speed ?

Comment: I mean to say instead of implementing the code using normal sql query, I was given a clue that oracle will notify the changes/updates in the tables occurred and based on which I have to develop code.  I was guessing it must something related to oracle api and jdbc and to my surprise I found this link on google which talks about notification service. Please guide me if i am going on right path? [link]http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28816

Answer (score 0):

**Data Migration** If you want to migrate data from one database to another database of different types,

Suppose you have `A` and `B` two different database, you have to export data from `A` database in `XML` format, table name is `XML` parent node (create structure as per your database).

Then parse that `XML's` and create objects of each table present in `A`, after that use any `XML` parser which will parse your `XML`, using hibernate save() api put each object in another database manage if tables has relationships in them then insert master table data first then insert child items data.

By this approach you no need to be dependent on destination (`B`) database each time, with the help of hibernate you can easily change your database.